# convert a row of a data frame to a simple vector in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I have a huge data frame from which I only select a couple of rows. Then I remove some of the columns based on a condition. let us say that I choose row 4460 as shown bellow:

```
        V1870 V107 V1315 V1867 V1544 V1207 V1252 V1765 V342 V429 V1826 V865 V1374
4460     0    0     3     0     5     0     2     0    4    0     0    0     0
```

The problem is that I need to convert this row to a simple vector ( meaning I should get rid of all the column/row names) so that I can pass it to another function. I would like to be able to have the following result:

```
    [1] 0 0 3 0 5 0 2 0 4 0 0 0 0
```

I tried `as.list` and `as.vector`, but none of them gave the results I was expecting. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example from `mtcars` data

```
mydata<-mtcars
k<-mydata[1,]
          mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
names(k)<-NULL

unlist(c(k))
 [1]  21.00   6.00 160.00 110.00   3.90   2.62  16.46   0.00   1.00   4.00   4.00
```

Updated as per @Ananda: `unlist(mydata[1, ], use.names = FALSE)`

Comment: I don't really get it. Why not just `unlist(mydata[1, ], use.names = FALSE)`?

Comment: Thank you so much, @ 
A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1
your solution is priceless; I had been searching for 1 hour, when I found your solution

Answer (score 1):

I think it's already a vector, only with names in each element (inherited from the data.frame).

```
    #random df
    DF = data.frame(col1 = sample(1:10, 10), col2 = sample(1:10,10), col3 = sample(1:10, 10))

    DF[5,]
      col1 col2 col3
    5    3    7    5

    mode(DF[5,]) 
    [1] "list"

    mode(unlist(DF[5,]))
    [1] "numeric"

    names(DF[5,])
    [1] "col1" "col2" "col3"

    sum(DF[5,]) # computations are naturally done
    [1] 15
```

To get rid of the names, nontheless, you could:

```
    unname(unlist(DF[5,]))
    [1] 3 7 5
```

Comment: `unlist` has a `use.names` argument which, when set to `FALSE` has the added benefit of being *much* faster than just using `unlist`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use row index.

e.q.

```
list <- yourdataframe[4460, ]
```