# Turn all data.table rows into a list R

Tags: r, list, data.table

Start with the following data.table:

```
set.seed(1234)
dt <- data.table(x = runif(3), y = runif(3), z = runif(3))

print(dt)
#         x         y           z
#1: 0.1137034 0.6233794 0.009495756
#2: 0.6222994 0.8609154 0.232550506
#3: 0.6092747 0.6403106 0.666083758
```

And turn it into a list in the following structure:

```
print(dt2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.1137034 0.6233794 0.009495756
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6222994 0.8609154 0.2325505
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.6092747 0.6403106 0.6660838
```

I've been studying the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340401/convert-a-row-of-a-data-frame-to-a-simple-vector-in-r), but have not been able to figure out how to do it for all rows of a data.table at once without applying a looping function. I'm trying to avoid a looping function because of the number of rows in the actual data.table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `data.table::transpose()` function:

```
transpose(as.list(dt))

#[[1]]
#[1] 0.113703411 0.623379442 0.009495756

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6222994 0.8609154 0.2325505

#[[3]]
#[1] 0.6092747 0.6403106 0.6660838
```

Comment: thanks, this got me 99% of the way there! To get exactly what I am looking for, I need to `unname` as such: `unname(as.list(transpose(dt))`

Comment: That's a good option. I updated a different version which saves the use of `unname`.